# Method namespaces/collections in Python classes

Tags: python, class, methods, namespaces

Say I have a class `Foo` and I do `foo = Foo()`. I want some kind of "method namespace" `foo.bar` that is not shared across `Foo` instances, to which I dynamically can add methods that operate on `foo`:

```
def method(self, someValue):
    self.value = someValue + 10

foo.bar.m = method
foo.bar.m(20)
```

And then I want to find that `foo.value` is 30.

Any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't understand. Your objective is to modify `foo.value` for certain (but not all) instances of the class `Foo`?

Comment: I want `self` in `method` to refer to `foo` when called as foo.bar.m(someInt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import types

class Namespace(object):
    pass

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.bar = Namespace()

def function(self, new_value):
    self.value = new_value

a = Foo(1)
b = Foo(2)

b.bar.function = types.MethodType(function, b, Foo)
b.bar.function(6)

print a.value   # prints 1
print b.value   # prints 6
```

The trick is using the `types` module to convert the test function into a method that can be bound to an instance of the object.

When I run this line: `b.bar.function = types.MethodType(function, b, Foo)`, I am essentially telling Python to create a new method that binds `function` to the `b` instance of `Foo`. I can then take this method and store it inside any arbitrary location.

Since the method is permanently bound to the `b` instance of `Foo`, `self` will always refer to `b` regardless of which object the method is actually assigned to.